# What is the right way to collect dumps through adplus?

Tags: debugging, windbg, adplus

I want to collect the hang dumps using adplus. Do I have to run the process with adplus command right from the start or do I have to start it once the application is hung? If it has to be done right from the start, is there way to reduce the size of dumps until the actual hung event happens?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the

```
%WinDbgPath%\ADPlus -hang -o %OUTDIR% -quiet –pn   <your.exe>
```

when you discover your.exe is hung. The size of the dump is depend of the type of dump and the size of the dumped process. You can control the type of dump in either command line options or in the .cfg file. 
This will produce an immediate dump, just as if you have attached with windbg and

```
.dump /ma /u  <file.dmp>
```

Comment: Also Take a look in the C:\Program Files (x86)\Debugging Tools for Windows (x86)\ adplus.doc
and the ADPlus section of windbg help.